# Dart type checking with generics

Tags: dart

I have a class:

```
  class StreamWithValue<T> extends Stream<T> {
  T value;
  ...
  }
```

and now:

```
  Stream<bool> _stream;
  StreamWithValue<bool> get stream=> _stream;
```

This compiles without errors even though its incorrect since obviously _stream isn't of type StreamWithValue. Is there a way for a more strict type checks? I am using Dart 2.1.2, Android Studio 3.3.2. Strangely the compiler correctly finds an error here:

```
  StreamWithValue get stream2 => _stream;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Dart 2 allows implicit downcasts to derived types.  To disallow them, in your `analysis_options.yaml` file (creating it if necessary), set:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```

Doing so will generate an analysis error:

> The return type 'Stream' isn't a 'StreamWithValue', as defined by the method 'stream'.

You might also be interested in setting:

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

For more information, see https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options.